# How to setup Gmail account on windows Phone 8 Emulator?

Tags: windows, windows-phone, windows-phone-emulator

I have installed Windows Phone 8 Emulator on my W8 PC. I am able to connect to access gmail through browser of Emulator, however when I am trying to configure Gmail in accounts under Settings, it is not not getting configured/

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you can do it through the phone.

Comment: i want to set it up on emulator only